# Removing an item from a session associative arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, session, cart, associative

I am really stuck with this. It is an array within an array such as:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [item] => product1 [unitprice] => 15 [quantity] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [item] => product2 [unitprice] => 15 [quantity] => 1 ) )
```

I have tried to remove a specific item using:

```
$pid=$_GET['id']; (where id = product1)

$delete=array_splice($_SESSION['cart'], array_search($id, $_SESSION['cart']), 1);
unset($delete);    

print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
```

This seems to randomly remove items. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
function searchForItem($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['item'] === $id) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}

$pid=$_GET['id'];

$id = searchForItem($pid, $_SESSION['cart']);

unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $index => $v) { 
    if(($key = array_search($pid, $v)) !== false) {
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$index]);
    }
}
```